# hough circle detection remove unnecessary circles

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, hough-transform

I am getting a lot of circles using hough circle detection algo on an image. how to make this detection more accurate?

picture showing circles detected.

[image]

original picture

[image]

FOLLOWING CODE IS USED

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('test_c.jpg',0)

img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)

cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles=cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

for i in circles[0,:]:

    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

cv2.imshow('detected circles',cimg)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()`
```

Comment: where did you copy that code? did you even read it? what do you think those parameters are good for? minRadius, maxRadius?

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this problem because you do not know how Hough transform works and because you did neither carefully read the code you most likely found somewhere online nor did you refer to the OpenCV reference documentation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_Hough_Transform

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghcircles

You have to restrict the radii. As Hough transform is more or less a brute force approach, this is very important. It greatly reduces calculation time and of course you can and should use this to only get circles of the radii you are looking for...

By setting a minimum distance between circles you avoid getting multiple results for one circle.

As always knowledge is the key to success.

Comment: Would you please explain the working of the hough circle detection algo. Is there better method to detect circles in image which is more accurate i.e. it does not gives more number of circles than there are. And thanks for your answer and much needed advice.

Comment: @ShubhamSingh which part of the wikipedia article I linked and the countless other resources you can find online did you not understand? It is not very polite to ask people for explainations if you have not even bothered to read what they gave you so far...